# RegEx for Javascript alphanumeric not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have the following script:

```
$('#txtUsername').keydown( function(evt) { 
   if (/^[a-z0-9]+$/i.test(String.fromCharCode(evt.keyCode)) == false)  {
      evt.returnValue = false; 
      return false;
   } 
});
```

The script above is supposed to prevent the user from entering in special character inside the user name field.  The problem is that this script allows typing of alphanumeric characters and it blocks `~_+-=[]{}\|;:'",<.>/?

I need this to also block and !@#$%^&*() characters.

What am I doing wrong?  I am testing this with latest Chrome browser.

**EDIT**
I know this is not the best way to validate a username, but I am questioning why regex is not showing the correct behavior.

jsFiddle click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/a0b8rgqs/)

Comment: Instead of Javascript, you may consider using [HTML5](http://html5pattern.com/Names) for this. Either way, as a reminder, actual validation should always be on the server.

Comment: I agree of the validation being on the server, but it is a customer requirement.  I will need to find a way to do this in Javascript.

Comment: Regardless of the requirement though, isnt /^[a-z0-9]+$/i is not supposed to allow !@#$%^&*()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`keydown` will only log which actual *key* on the keyboard was pressed, not the character which was entered, e.g. on a UK keyboard `%` is entered with `shift+5`, so `keydown` will only pick up the `5` key and so accept the input.

You should `keypress` instead:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#txtUsername').keypress(function (evt) {
        if (/^[a-z0-9]+$/i.test(String.fromCharCode(evt.keyCode)) == false) {
            evt.returnValue = false;
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a0b8rgqs/2/)

Answer (score 3):

Use the `keypress` event, not `keydown`. When you use `keydown`, entering <kbd>@</kbd> is seen as pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> followed by <kbd>2</kbd>, and `2` is allowed by the regexp. `keypress` gets the merged key codes.

Also, `evt.returnValue` is deprecated. The proper way to prevent the normal event handler from running is by calling `evt.preventDefault()`.

```js
$('#txtUsername').keypress(function(evt) {
  if (/^[a-z0-9]+$/i.test(String.fromCharCode(evt.keyCode)) == false) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="txtUsername" />
```